# How to type a composed function with spread arguments in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

As far as I know, spread operator types are Arrays. In this case `fn(...args)` returns the following error :

> "Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type
>   'never' has no compatible call signatures."

I've tried a few options but couldn't come up with a solution.

```js
const callAll = (...fns: []) => (...args: []) => fns.forEach(fn => fn && fn(...args));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[]` is actually an empty tuple, and as such an item of that tuple is of type `never` (ie something that can never exist as far as typescript is concerned). If you want an array of items you don't want checked `any[]` would be the way to write that.

```
const callAll = (...fns: any[]) => (...args: any[]) => fns.forEach(fn => fn && fn(...args))
```

While this would pass the compiler it is not very type safe, we can call `callAll` with any arguments and typescript would not complain (`callAll(1,2,3)` is ok from a compiler point of view)

The first improvement would be to tell typescript that the array passed to `fn` must be an array of functions:

```
const callAll = (...fns: Array<(...a: any[])=> any>) => (...args: any[]) => fns.forEach(fn => fn && fn(...args));

const composed = callAll(a => console.log("a " + a), b => console.log("b " + b))
composed("arg");
```

I used the `Array<T>` syntax instead of `T[]` the two represent the same type, but since `T` is a function signature (`(...a: any[])=> any`) this syntax is easier to read. The function signature will allow any function into the array, without corelating them in any way.

While an improvement this is still not perfect. There is no checking that the parameters to all of the functions match and these match with the arguments passed in.

We can do even better, checking that parameter types match and argument types also match. To do this we will need to add generic type parameters to our function. `P` will represent the types of the parameters. This will let us forward the parameter types to the returned function, and also enforce that all functions must have the same parameter types:

```
const callAll = <P extends any[]>(...fns: Array<(...a: P)=> void>) => (...args: P) => fns.forEach(fn => fn && fn(...args));

const composed = callAll(
    (a: string) => console.log("a " + a), // only first one must specify param types
    b => console.log("b " + b)
) // b is inferred as string
composed("arg");
composed(1); //error must be strings

const composedBad = callAll(
    (a: string) => console.log("a " + a), 
    (b: number) => console.log("b " + b) // error parametr types don't match
)
```